# With stripe Checkout, how do I keep track of the payment status

Tags: stripe-payments

In the stripe documentation, it says:

[image]

So in this case, the checkout page goes to the success or failed page on my frontend.

I use the backend to track the payment status so that we can monitor the transactions in the admin portal, and the above approach seems dangerous to me.

When checkout is successful, it redirects the window to the success url. This means I have to call the backend API in the success page to update the payment status. However, the stripe is the source of truth about the payment status, and the status update on DB should come from Stripe, not come from a frontend page. At the very minimum, if a user refreshes the success page, it would have called the API again and again which is bad. Also, it is about "a user says I paid successfully" v.s. "Stripe says they paid successfully".

I tried the Stripe webhooks, but in the webhook data object, there is no information that I can use to link it to the sessionId that is generated from creating the checkout session, but the session id is the only tracking id I can get from Stripe about a payment.

What's the best practice, if Checkout is the only solution, to securely update my database?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Rely on webhooks. The `checkout.session.completed` event will describe a Checkout Session which contains its ID, which you hopefully saved when you created the Session earlier so you can link the two together.
2. Retrieve the session ID from the [success URL](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) once the payment is complete and retrieve the Session on your server, then check the Session's [`payment_status`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_status). This way your server can verify if the payment was actually completed or if someone just managed to guess the URL of your success page.

Stripe doesn't recommend only doing option 2, as it's very possible that users close the browser tab or window before the redirect to your success page can happen, resulting in a possible loss of payment confirmation. You should always use webhooks instead to guarantee your purchase fulfillment logic correctly fires.

Comment: thanks for answering. Glad to learn about the checkout.session.completed webhook. For session 2 though, if the success url goes to the server, then the browser's success page will not be triggered ( I dont think there is a way to call two success urls, or let the server redirects the checkout page on frontend).

Comment: You could also create a cron task to periodically check the payment status of checkout sessions, or queue a task to happen a specific time after the checkout session is created.

Comment: Excellent!

The remark about the possibility of the user closing their browser finally and conclusively puts the often-asked question to rest: "if we have the success URL then why do we still need Webhooks?"

Answer (score 3):

webhook is always an option but you could also manually check via the session id post payment:

```js
const session = await stripeObj.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      checkoutSessionId
    );
    if (session.payment_status === "paid") {
      console.log("user is paid now");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Stripe Payment status or session Details by session_id on asp.net core || .Net 5

```
var service = new SessionService();
Session session = service.Get(yourSessionId);


// You can track :-
session.Id;
session.PaymentStatus; // Paid or Unpaid
session.Status;
session.Mode;
//And more
```